# Publish a non https endpoint for WCF - Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

How can I add a non https endpoint for a WCF ? My WCF is a web role in an Azure project.

My current endpoint is :

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SecureBasic" proxyAddress="http://localhost:80">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>


    <services>
      <service name="WebRoleUploadImages.UploadImages">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>           
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:80"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="WCFSecure" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecureBasic"
          name="SecureHTTPSendpoint" contract="WebRoleUploadImages.IUploadImages"> </endpoint>       

      </service>
    </services>
```

The thing is I do not yet have an SSL certificate so I cannot test my app without an http endpoint

Comment: Have you thought about testing using a [self-signed certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate)? Depending on your application/use-case things might behave quite differently with and without SSL which makes testing kind of worthless.

Comment: I did use a self signed certificate but it says : 'There was no endpoint listening at https://myserver/UploadImages.svc/WCFSecure that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.'

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an azure limitation, but a WCF limitation. Basic authentication sends the password in plain text, and doing that without an SSL certification is a horribly bad idea. If it's only for testing you can cheat it by specifying

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
```